# E-Mail notification when cell reaches date - status update does not work

Tags: vba, excel, email, status

I finally made it happen that my macro at least works 90%. Every time I open my Excel file, automatic e-mails are sent out to the right people.

However, I have one issue, which I cannot solve: I was hoping to implement a status, sent vs not sent, which triggers whether another e-Mail should be sent the next day.

Unfortunately, the status never updates.
I would be very happy if you can have a look at it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim FormulaRange As Range
Dim FormulaCell As Range
Dim NotSentMsg As String
Dim MyMsg As String
Dim SentMsg As String
Dim Deadline As Double

NotSentMsg = "Not Sent"
SentMsg = "Sent"

Deadline = Date

Set FormulaRange = Me.Range("S2:S64")

On Error GoTo EndMacro:
For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
    With FormulaCell
        If .Value < Deadline Then
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
                If .Offset(0, 3).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                    Call Mail_with_outlook1(FormulaCell)
                End If
            Else
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
            End If
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        .Offset(0, 3).Value = MyMsg
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
Next FormulaCell



ExitMacro:
Exit Sub

EndMacro:
Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
     & vbLf & Err.Number _
     & vbLf & Err.Description
End Sub


Sub Mail_with_outlook1(FormulaCell As Range)
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strto As String, strcc As String, strbcc As String
Dim strsub As String, strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strto = Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "T").Value
strcc = Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "U").Value
strbcc = ""
strsub = "Notice Period in 6 Months"
strbody = "Hi " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "D").Value & _
        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The notice period for your customer " & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "A").Value & " is in 180 days." & _
          vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Thank you very much and feel free to reach out to me in case of any question." & _
          vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Best regards, Marius"



With OutMail
    .To = strto
    .CC = strcc
    .BCC = strbcc
    .Subject = strsub
    .Body = strbody
    'You can add a file to the mail like this
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    .Display    ' or use .Send
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The SentMsg is never set, you are only using NotSentMsg, as far as I see

Comment: Hi Roland, Thank you for you answer. Based on your comment and the fresh mindset of the next day I finally figured it out. I have to move the line after the first if statement 'MyMsg = NotMsgSent' to after the second if statement. Then it works perfectly fine. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome, Marius - glad you were able to solve your problme. Please note that on StackOverflow you shouldn't put "Solved" in the title. If your Answer could help others the correct thing to do is write up an ANSWER containing the solution and the reason that solved the initial problem. You can then mark that as "the" Answer. On the other hand, if you think the answer was "ridiculously simple" and something that wouldn't happen to others you can flag your question for deletion so that it's removed from the site.

Answer (score 0):

Answer on comment.

Thanks Roland, 
Based on your comment and the fresh mindset of the next day I finally figured it out.

I have to move the line after the first if statement **`'MyMsg = NotMsgSent'`** to after the second if statement, Then it works perfectly fine. Thank you!